# How to interpret this octal dump?

Tags: dump, octal

```
echo 10 > ten
od ten 
0000000 030061 000012
0000003

od -b ten
0000000 061 060 012
0000003
```

the second output is easy to understand (1 0 and newline) while I am totally lost on the first output, how to read "030061 000012" as 10?

Thanks,

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like `od` by default uses `-t o2` meaning octal short (2 bytes) and your architecture is [little endian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Endianness). This means that the most significant byte is stored after the least significant byte, so:

```
`1`     `0`              ASCII
0x31     0x30            Hex
00110001 00110000        Binary
0 011 000 000 110 001    Binary Short (note bytes swapped)
0   3   0   0   6   1    Octal
```

Answer (score 1):

`030061` == `0x3031`, swap byte order and you get `'1','0'`, `000012` is newline again